# Product Information Not Vaild HP Laptop

Tags: linux, hardware-detection, hp-elitebook, hp

I got this error on my laptop (HP Folio 9470m) which shows that the product information is not valid. Upon search, I found that it usually occurs after changing the motherboard, (which I didn't, It was fine last night and today when I started it there was this error). Now the issue is I use Linux and the tutorials I found online are for windows only, the bigger issue is I live in a village and no one has a PC or a Laptop that I know plus we don't have an internet cafe as well. So I want to know if anyone can guide me on how to fix this on Linux, I use Archcraft it is an Arch Based Distro.

Comment: A screenshot would be useful.  Linux does not require any kind of license.

Comment: The screen comes from the "wonderful" HP firmware @davidgo . [Here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/217491i23BF24AFA52E0E5E?v=v2) is a picture of what he is talking about.  There are many flavors of this screen but they are all firmware and they all suck.  All fixes I see on the internet require making boot media using windows tools.  I guess it is possible that these could be made from Linux but I have no idea how to make PC-DOS boot media from Linux.  It also appears (0% science) that this is not common in western countries.